# Unequal sample size i independent t test

Tags: t-test, sample-size

I have a data to compare two group let say Group A and Group B. The sample size for group A is 20 and Group B is 57. The outcomes variables are normally distributed as according to Shapiro-Wilk test in SPSS. The variance between these two groups are equal (which is showed by leven's equality test). it seemed that all the assumptions of independent T-test are fulfilled.

THE t-test results showed that there is significance difference between the mean of two groups.

I am wondering whether results like this is valid?
if small sample size can cause loss of power (type II ERROR high- the probablity of false negative result- probability not reject instead the hypothesis is not true), how if the sample size small and significance still presence?

Thanks.

Comment: "*The outcomes variables are normally distributed as according to Shapiro-Wilk test in SPSS.*" -- no. Failure to reject the null doesn't imply the null is true.

Comment: One of the main points of significance and p-values is that they have the same meaning regardless of sample size (even though, as you correctly state, small samples tend to have little power).

Answer (score -4):

What is the p-value you got? 
You must check the p-value which is the best approach to reject or accept a hypothesis in hypothesis testing. 
The smaller the p-value the more significant is the result.

Comment: -1 does not adress the concerns and presents a very naive approach to hypothesis testing.